# How to copy data from one database/table to another database/table in oracle using toad

Tags: oracle, toad

I am trying to copy a table data from dev box db to uat db which are 2 different data bases . I am trying in toad.All the connection details are correct but its not working and throwing the following error.

[Error] Execution (12: 1): ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

This is what i am trying

```
copy from abc/cde@//abc.abc.com:1521/devbox to abc/cde@//abc.abc.com/uatbox 
  INSERT TOOL_SERVICE_MAPPING (*) 
  USING (SELECT * FROM TOOL_SERVICE_MAPPING)
```

Comment: How did you come up with this command? This looks nothing like a standard SQL.

Comment: yes its big mistake i am trying based on your suggestion now.

Answer (score 6):

If your table doesn't have a huge number of rows you can use Toad's Export function: it creates an insert statement for each row. You can then run these statements in destination DB to re-create your table's data.

Here are the steps:

**A. Create a copy of the table in destination DB**

1. in source DB in a schema browser window click on the table you want to copy, select "**script**" tab in the right part of the window: you will find the script to re-create your table; copy this script
2. paste the script in a new SQL editor window in destination DB and run it. This should create the new table

**B. Copy data in new table**

1. in a schema browser window right click on table name in source DB
2. select "**Export Data**" from context menu
3. write "**where**" statement of your export query (leave it blank if you want to copy the entire table)
4. select destination: clipboard
5. click "**ok**" (now insert statements are stored in your clipboard)
6. paste insert statements in a new SQL editor window in destination DB
7. run statements as script (shortcut F5)

Answer (score 4):

`copy` is a SQL*Plus command, not a SQL statement.  I would be surprised if Toad had implemented that particular SQL*Plus command (it does implement many of the simpler commands).  If you want to use the `copy` command, you would need to use SQL*Plus, not Toad.

If you want to use Toad, you would need to use a SQL statement to copy the data.  You could create a database link in the destination database that points to the source database and then

```
INSERT INTO tool_service_mapping
  SELECT *
    FROM tool_service_mapping@<<db link to source database>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easyest and most error-free way I have experienced so far is: Database->Compare->Schemas

It's not too complicated as it looks (lots of checkboxes), but you tick boxes for objects you need to be created in an empty database, and at the end of comparison you end up with SQL script including all objects (triggers, views, sequences, packges) that you selected (checkboxes).

I clearly see all tables, triggers, data, etc in generated sql script and even can tick these I don't wish to create (if any)... Before executing script, TOAD asks you to confirm against which database you are running the script - saved me few times... As ackward as it looks, it works perfectly.

I have arround 200 tables I don't know if this is suitable for huge databases.